# Differentiating absolute value functions using sympy in python won't return an answer

Tags: python, sympy, absolute-value

I'm trying to find the maximum points of curvature of a `tanh(x)` function, but the mathematical definition for curvature contains an absolute value function. I've specified that x must be real-valued which resolves sympy returning an imaginary function for the derivative of the curvature. However when trying to solve for `k'(x)=0` using the `sym.solve()` method python will simply continue running and not return an answer at all.

```
x = sym.symbols('x', real=True)

# below are parameters I found from curve fitting raw data elsewhere that are just converted to sympy variables

a = sym.Float(a)  
b = sym.Float(b)
c = sym.Float(c)
d = sym.Float(d)

# function in question
def f(x):
    return a * sym.tanh(b * x + c) + d

def fprime(x):
    return sym.diff(f(x),x,1)

def f2prime(x):
    return sym.diff(f(x),x,2)

f1 = fprime(x)
f2 = f2prime(x)

# mathematical definition of curvature
def kappa(f1,f2):
    return sym.Abs(f2) / ( 1 + f1**2 )**(3/2)

def kprime(f1,f2):
    return sym.diff(kappa(f1,f2),x,1)

k1 = kprime(f1,f2)
print(k1)
```

One combination of the constants `a,b,c,d=[-2.40402847 -3.20154993  0.51489147 -8.05771537]` and `k1` was

```
0.324273723818531*(1 - tanh(0.514891472285591 - 3.2015499273203*x)**2)*((1 - tanh(0.514891472285591 - 3.2015499273203*x)**2)**2 + 0.0168810800591381)**(-2.5)*(6.40309985464061*tanh(0.514891472285591 - 3.2015499273203*x)**2 - 6.40309985464061)*tanh(0.514891472285591 - 3.2015499273203*x)*Abs((tanh(3.2015499273203*x - 0.514891472285591)**2 - 1)*tanh(3.2015499273203*x - 0.514891472285591)) + 0.108091241272844*((3.2015499273203 - 3.2015499273203*tanh(3.2015499273203*x - 0.514891472285591)**2)*(tanh(3.2015499273203*x - 0.514891472285591)**2 - 1) + (6.40309985464061 - 6.40309985464061*tanh(3.2015499273203*x - 0.514891472285591)**2)*tanh(3.2015499273203*x - 0.514891472285591)**2)*((1 - tanh(0.514891472285591 - 3.2015499273203*x)**2)**2 + 0.0168810800591381)**(-1.5)*sign((tanh(3.2015499273203*x - 0.514891472285591)**2 - 1)*tanh(3.2015499273203*x - 0.514891472285591))
```

Then trying to solve this for x using `print(sym.solve(k1),x)` could never return an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a pretty high-order nonlinear equation. Try `nsolve`:

```
>>> nsolve(k1, -.5)
-0.427127686132521
```

Comment: Thank you this works! It seems however that nsolve is a bit of a finicky algorithm because using the same initial condition it couldn't seem to find a root and choosing other starting values gives me roots around 7 or -7 but I know there should be two roots somewhere between -1 and 1.

Comment: The root that was detected near -0.4 appears to be a discontinuity. There appears to be another near 0.16. Unless you are using bisection and know you are bracketing a root, false roots (like +/-7) are an issue when the function is nearly 0.